# Error in connecting to GKE cluster from Google Cloud Build

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to connect to GKE cluster in Google cloud build, i performed below build step

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - container
      - clusters
      - get-credentials
      - cluster-name
      - '--zone=us-central1-a'
```

Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://IP/version": error executing access token command "/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=exit status 127 output= stderr=/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: exec: line 192: python: not found

Update: Though it can be done using gcloud, using `kubectl` cloud-builder seems to be good idea here to connect to GKE cluster.
You can directly mention few Environment Variables and kubectl will do the rest for you.

Refer to this link: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/kubectl#usage

My build step looks like this:

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
    env:
      - CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-a
      - CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=cluster-name
      - KUBECONFIG=/workspace/.kube/config
    args:
      - cluster-info
```

Comment: Is your cluster private?

Comment: No, it is public cluster!